# VBA find and move a cell with exact word - more complex than the title suggests

Tags: excel, vba, text, move

I promise I have searched for this answer before coming here to ask;

I'm trying to create a VBA to search column J for the word "To". If it is found it needs to move the cell to column L.

What I am struggling with is that it only needs to move if "To" is on its own. I have cells that contain, for example, "To Sarah" but these need to stay in its place.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?
Many thanks
Pip

Comment: So the idea is to loop through the cells of column J and test each cell if it is `To` or not. If it is `To` move it to L and if not proceed with the next cell. Have you tried to write a code for this? Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments in the code for explanation.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    ' define worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' find last used row in column J
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' collect all cells with "To" in this variable
    Dim FoundCells As Range
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow  ' loop through cells in J
        If ws.Cells(iRow, "J").Value = "To" Then  ' check if the cell is "To"
            ' if yes add the cell to FoundCells
            If FoundCells Is Nothing Then  ' first cell found
                Set FoundCells = ws.Cells(iRow, "J")
            Else  ' all other cells found
                Set FoundCells = Union(FoundCells, ws.Cells(iRow, "J"))
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow
    
    If Not FoundCells Is Nothing Then
        ' copy found "To" values 2 columns to the right
        FoundCells.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value = FoundCells.Value
    
        ' delete found "To" vaules (from column J)
        FoundCells.Clear
    Else
        MsgBox "No cells with ""To"" were found."
    End If
End Sub
```

We loop through all used cells in column J, check each cell if it is `To` and if so collect the cell in `FoundCells`. In the end we copy the `To` values from those cells 2 columns to the right and delete the `To` values in the found cells.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Peh, I really appreciated it.
Unfortunately, my inexperience with coding is shining through, as I mainly search for code and use trial and error to make it work. 
The codes I have tried move everything in the cell if it finds "to" in it.

I have added your code and it is returning with
Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

on

FoundCells.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value = FoundCells.Value

Comment: @PipS see my edited code. I added a test if something was found because if nothing was found it might cause the error you describe. Please check it out.